# Show value from console Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, console

How can I show the values from `li` with a class in Chrome? For example, on Instagram we can show the list with all followers wiith the next method:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('wo9IH'));
```

With this, we obtain a `HTML.collection` like an `Array`.

[image]

But I just want to show or see the name from my followers. How can I do it? I tried with a for cicle:

```
function names(){
    for (var i=0; i <document.getElementsByClassName("wFPL8").length; i++ ){
    var singleElement = document.getElementsByClassName("wFPL8")[i];
    console.log(singleElement.innerHTML);
}
}

names();
```

But this show names and spaces like this:

[image]

how can i delete this spaces?

Comment: You can do `.value` or `.innerHTML`

Comment: Yeah, on my for cicle i use `innerHTML` but if you see the second image for any motive add a space

Answer (score 0):

You can test that the innerHTML isn't empty and only print it out if there is a name in your for loop.

```
if(singleElement.innerHTML.length > 0)
    console.log(singleElement.innerHTML);
```